# LOGIC GATES and logic circuits in a calculator

Tags: digital-logic, optoelectronics

i am tasked to do a circuit using logic gates regarding the work of a calculator. it is said that how can we make number 3 shown in a calculator represented by logic gates. can someone help me?

i need to light the sections that will form the number 3.

like this image.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE!. It depends on where do you want to display the number. A 7-segmented display, LCD.. ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise that this is not a free design
house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied
out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question
shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your
post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and
findings so far, in considerable detail. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: @Jessa, you wouldn't need any gates just to show a '3' on a calculator. You could wire up the display to permanently show a '3'. There must be more to the question. For example, "Using gates show how to calculate and display the sum of two 3-bit binary numbers".

Comment: hi, i added a pic, thought it might help elaborate my problem.

Comment: actually, this topic was not discussed to us thoroughly so I am not familiar with the terms, sorry.

Comment: A good place to start would be looking up how a 7 segment decoder IC works

Answer (score 2):

Since this seems to be homework we won't give you a full answer but will guide you through.

1. Name the segments on your seven-segment display.

[image]

*Figure 1. Standard segment naming. Image source: [7-segment display basics](http://lednique.com/display-technology/7-segment-display-basics/).*

2. Next create a table to show what segments are required by each digit. e.g.

*Table 1. 7-segment decoder.*

```
         Binary     Segment
Decimal  d c b a    A B C D E F G
      0  0 0 0 0    1 1 1 1 1 1 0
      1  0 0 0 1    0 1 1 0 0 0 0
      2  0 0 1 0    ....
```

3. Write the equations for each segment.
4. Draw the logic diagram.

Update your question with your work and we'll follow from there.

Comment: Between steps 2 and 3 would probably be helpful to turn the truth table for each segment into a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: that's what i exactly did. i figured out the segments that will be affected. and now im stuck figuring out the logic diagram specifically of C. because i cant separate 1 from 2 since 1 will be affected and 2 will not.

Comment: I've reorganised Table 1 to make it a little easier to work with. Copy it into your question and finish all the rows then you should be able to proceed to the next step. Ping me with `@transistor` to let me know when you're ready.